# Use class name to set id dynamically

Tags: jquery

I need to set an ID to element on click event, and it should have the same name as a class.
For example, when I click on element with class="x", I want to set id="x" to this element.

I tried to do that with following code, but it doesn't work

```
$(this).click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('x')){
           $(this).attr('id', 'x');
           console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
```

When I change $(this) to specified element ($('.x') for example), it does work, but I want that click event work with ANY clicked elements.

Comment: Element IDs have to be unique in a document. Your code suggests you're attempting to apply the same id to multiple elements.

Comment: What does the first `this` in that initial selector refer to?  What larger context are you running this code in?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this? Is there some relevance to be able to catch the id later for something? If you have 10 elements with class `x` on the page, setting the ID with the counter as answered by lonut is the best method.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be like this:

```
var count = 0; //added a count to have unique ids
    $('.x').on('click', function(){
           count++;
           if($(this).hasClass('x')){
               $(this).attr('id', 'x_' + count); 
           }
    });
```

Ids always need to be different. You can't have the same two, or more ids. It messes with the whole concept of using them.

Answer (score 1):

you can do in short form

```
$(document).on('click', '.x', function () {$(this).attr('id', 'x');});
```

**Purpose of ID is unique identifies of any dome element in page.** so it is not good to overwrite it or give same value to different elements

So I suggest to use data-id attribute instead of id

```
$(document).on('click', '.x', function () {
     $(this).attr('data-id', 'x');
     console.log($(this).data('id', 'x')); //for retrieve data-id 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting your initial `$(this)` isn't what you're actually trying to click on. If you want to listen to every click on the page and then test it, attach a listener to the document and test the event target.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.hasClass('x')) {
        $target.attr('id', 'x');
        console.log($target.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of $('some-selector'), I want to handle event to any clicked element

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand but I think that the listener have to be on a correct selector, try with :

```
$('*').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('x')){
       $(this).attr('id', 'x');
       console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of attaching the listener to every element on the page you should listen for clicks on `document` and then test `e.target`: `$(document).click(function (e) { console.log(e.target); })`

Comment: Instead of $('*'), I want to handle event on any clicked element